# Split text string into column based on variable

Tags: r, regex, text, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a text column that I would like to split into multiple columns since the text string contains multiple variables, such a location, education, distance etc.

Dataframe:

```
text.string = c("&location=NY&distance=30&education=University", 
                "&location=CA&distance=30&education=Highschool&education=University", 
                "&location=MN&distance=10&industry=Healthcare", 
                "&location=VT&distance=30&education=University&industry=IT&industry=Business") 

df = data.frame(text.string)
df


                                                                  text.string
1                               &location=NY&distance=30&education=University
2          &location=CA&distance=30&education=Highschool&education=University
3                                &location=MN&distance=10&industry=Healthcare
4 &location=VT&distance=30&education=University&industry=IT&industry=Business
```

I can split this using `cSplit`: `cSplit(df, 'text.string', sep = "&")`:

```
   text.string_1 text.string_2 text.string_3        text.string_4        text.string_5     text.string_6
1:            NA   location=NY   distance=30 education=University                   NA                NA
2:            NA   location=CA   distance=30 education=Highschool education=University                NA
3:            NA   location=MN   distance=10  industry=Healthcare                   NA                NA
4:            NA   location=VT   distance=30 education=University          industry=IT industry=Business
```

Problem is that the text string may contain a multiple of the same variable, or some miss a certain variable. With `cSplit` the grouping of the variables per column become all mixed up. I would like to avoid this, and group them together.

So it would like similar to this (`education` and `industry` do not appear in multiple columns anymore):

```
  text.string_1 text.string_2 text.string_3                             text.string_4                 text.string_5 text.string_6
1            NA   location=NY   distance=30                      education=University                          <NA>            NA
2            NA   location=CA   distance=30 education=Highschool education=University                          <NA>            NA
3            NA   location=MN   distance=10                                      <NA>           industry=Healthcare            NA
4            NA   location=VT   distance=30                      education=University  industry=IT industry=Business            NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account @NicE comment:
This is one way, following your example:

```
library(data.table)
       text.string = c("&location=NY&distance=30&education=University", 
                    "&location=CA&distance=30&education=Highschool&education=University", 
                    "&location=MN&distance=10&industry=Healthcare", 
                    "&location=VT&distance=30&education=University&industry=IT&industry=Business") 

    clean <- strsplit(text.string, "&|=")
    out <- lapply(clean, function(x){ma <- data.table(matrix(x[!x==""], nrow = 2, byrow = F ));
    setnames(ma, as.character(ma[1,]));
    ma[-1,]})

    out <- rbindlist(out, fill = T)
    out
       location distance  education  education   industry industry
    1:       NY       30 University         NA         NA       NA
    2:       CA       30 Highschool University         NA       NA
    3:       MN       10         NA         NA Healthcare       NA
    4:       VT       30 University         NA         IT Business
```

Comment: How would you do the `dcast`? You need to add an `id` variable to track from which line each variable comes from.

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts! However, is there a way for `strsplit` to take a column of a data frame? Since my strings are in a data frame, I would very much like to do something like this `clean <- strsplit(df$text.string, "&|=")`

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting you correctly, but you can use also lapply over each colum, something lapply(dataframe, strsplit). But, if I'm not, please provide the complete reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not that clear, essentially the strings that need to be split are in a single column of a data frame. For example, in my post that column would be `df$text.string`. I hope the situation is more clear now.

Comment: In that case, you are answering your question, just input `df$text.string` directly, `strsplit(df$text.string, "&|=")` , is this what you want?

Comment: Yes exactly! But when I do that I get an error: `Error in strsplit(df$text.string, "&|=") : non-character argument`. That's why I am a bit confused.

Comment: humm... try this `data.frame(text.string = c("&location=NY&distance=30&education=University", 
                                 "&location=CA&distance=30&education=Highschool&education=University", 
                                 "&location=MN&distance=10&industry=Healthcare", 
                                 "&location=VT&distance=30&education=University&industry=IT&industry=Business"), stringsAsFactors = F )`

Comment: That was it! In my df the column was somehow formatted as factors! Thanks a lot!